# Comparing two tables in different sheets

Tags: excel

I have two tables (A and B) in different sheets. Each of the table has two columns (ID and Holdings). How can I check if Holdings of that particular ID from Table A match the same ID's Holdings in Table B? In this [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sg7ZG.png) you can see the desired result. What would be the EXCEL function in this case for it to return TRUE if the Holding amounts match and FALSE if the Holding amounts differ?

[Screenshot from the EXCEL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sg7ZG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good time to use INDEX-MATCH

H3 would be

```
= IFERROR(G3 = INDEX($B$3..$B$6, MATCH(F3, $A$3..$A$6, 0)), FALSE)
```

excel-easy.com has a good writeup of INDEX-MATCH [here](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/index-match.html).